# Уведомление в Android

Tags: java, android, api, сервисы, уведомления

Приложение при запуске(открытии) получает данные от API. Как сделать так, чтобы приложение выводило уведомление, если какое-то значение, полученное с API совпадёт с определённым значением?

Comment: android studio - среда разработки, она не получает данные в созданные с ее помощью приложения

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам простейший пример создания уведомления:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
           .setContentTitle("Заголовок")
           .setContentText("Текст уведомления");

Notification notification = builder.build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification); // Тут мы запускаем показ уведомления. 1 - это идентификатор уведомления, чтобы работать с ним после, если нужно...
```

Подробнее прочитать о уведомлениях можно [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification).